# How to execute a Python tool installed in Python virtual environment from Java

Tags: java, python, pip, virtualenv

I want to run a Python tool installed in a python virtual environment from Java source code. What are the possible Java libraries that I can use for this purpose?

I have already tried below code:
`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/Users/xxx/Documents/venv/bin/python3.7 yyy);`

But this code doesn't work. It is to run a Python script (eg., `yyy= script.py`) from the virtual environment (`venv`). Therefore, it gives me an error saying there is no file called `yyy`. But my requirement is to run a Python tool installed in the virtual environment `venv`.

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement might need a little clarification, but I suspect you can make it work with a [`ProcessBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/class-use/ProcessBuilder.html). Use [`directory(File)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#directory-java.io.File-) to control the working directory for the command. And [`inheritIO()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#inheritIO--) to make stdio work "automatically". Never hardcode a user's home folder. You can use [`System.getProperty(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperty-java.lang.String-) to retrieve the home folder.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder();
pb.directory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "Documents/venv/"));
pb.inheritIO();
try {
    Process p = pb.command("bin/python3.7",
            "lib/python3.7/site-packages/yyy").start();
    p.waitFor();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

It might be better to use [`System.getenv(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv-java.lang.String-) instead of relying on `"Documents/venv"` to contain the pyvenv root.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this gives me an error `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'yyy': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`. I got the same error with `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/Users/xxx/Documents/venv/bin/python3.7 yyy);`

Comment: You haven't run pip install on yyy to that venv.

Comment: I already have. I checked it several times. :( I do not why it checks this file location `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python`

Comment: Try using exact path of the python tool `yyy`. For an example : Process p = `pb.command("bin/python3.7", "..venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/yyy")`

Comment: I had to provide the path of the tool `yyy` as @Malinda mentioned. Please consider amending your answer. @Elliott